# I am getting the project is missing required library: RestAssuredJar\\rest-assured-4.1.1.jar'"

Tags: java, maven, automation, pom.xml

in my project I am getting
is missing required library: RestAssuredJar\rest-assured-4.1.1.jar'",

I am trying to run this in maven terminal and in my pom.xml file I have

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
   <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
   <version>4.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

any help appreciated.

how to get rid of this?

Comment: Execute `mvn clean install` to see whether or not your problem got resolved.